# Purge Command Discord.JS Works But Error Pops Up?

Tags: discord.js

const Command = require('../../Structures/Command');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

```
module.exports = class extends Command {

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args, {
            aliases: ['clear']
        });
    }

    async run(message, args) {
            // This command removes all messages from all users in the channel, up to 100.
            if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS"))
              return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this!");
            // get the delete count, as an actual number.
            const deleteCount = parseInt(args[0], 10);

            // Ooooh nice, combined conditions. <3
            if(!deleteCount || deleteCount < 1 || deleteCount > 100)
              return message.reply("Please provide a number between 1 and 100 for the number of messages to delete");

            // So we get our messages, and delete them. Simple enough, right?
            const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: deleteCount});
            message.channel.send(fetched.size + ` deleted messages by ${message.author.tag}`).then(msg => {msg.delete(2000)});
            message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)   
    }

};
```

This works perfectly but there is an error saying:

```
(node:1132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at Message.delete (C:\Users\xdswe\Desktop\Zero\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:501:44)
    at C:\Users\xdswe\Desktop\Zero\src\commands\Utilities\Purge.js:26:118
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:1132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=s
trict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

That's caused by the last part of your code, since discord.js v12 `Message.delete()` needs an object with the options `timeout` and `reason` which are optional, but in your case you want `timeout` to be `2000` like so:

```js
// So we get our messages, and delete them. Simple enough, right?
const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: deleteCount});
message.channel.send(fetched.size + ` deleted messages by ${message.author.tag}`)
  .then(msg => {msg.delete({ timeout: 2000 })});
message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
```

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to SO, if an answer solves your question, accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know what worked and also that the question has been answered